# How can I create processes in a microservice architecture or achieve similar design

Tags: c#, azure, process, architecture, microservices

Currently I have a MVC Web application which is hosted on IIS on a windows server in Azure. On the same VM, I also have a console application (MyConsoleApp.exe).

The Web application is aware of the location of the MyConsoleApp.exe. Through the Web application, I can create and kill processes. Every time I create a process through the UI, the Web application will create a new process running the MyApplication.exe. The process information is logged to a SQL database (PID and GUID) and then through the UI I can decide to kill the process or fetch information each console app has logged.

The diagram below shows the architecture with 3 processes created running the console app. N number of processes can be created. This is just an example.

[image]

I would like to transform my applications into microservices using .net core, and I am also replacing SQL with Mongo.

My question is, how I can replace the part where I create separate processes through the Web app? The Web app as a microservice will run on its own container. I was thinking of spinning up containers remotely, to imitate what each process is currently doing, but it sounds awful.

Could you please suggest an architectural solution or design I could consider implementing?

My vision is something like this, but the processes part is troubling me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is usually accomplished by spinning up workers at then end of a queue.  This is detailed in Microsoft's [Reference Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/scalable-web-app) where they talk about [Function Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I read the recommended and also read about durable functions, which are meant for longer running processes. The idea is great, and durable functions can be triggered via http requests too, which is awesome in my  case. But one thing i noticed is about the cost of these functions. My processes could run for days, and i usually have more than 3 of them running. Also when a process stops because of expected conditiona, i would initialte another one. I think durable functions are a great idea, but i believe it would cost me alot and not sure i can afford it.

Comment: These aren't really meant to have these processes run for days at a time.  I think they have a max execution time of 5-10 minutes.  From a cost standpoint it would be negligible.  they are billed on a  $0.000016/GB-second basis.  So if these processes have 3 running all the time, that would be around $4 / month if you were running 3 at a time full-time...  The trick is to get it so that they are more periodic and not running continuously.    If there isn't a way to get that to happen, you likely will need to use the same architecture, but host the processes on a VM yourself.

Comment: Regardless of the implementation, you probably want to communicate with those processes via a queue.  Sending work to them and spinning up new ones as needed.

Comment: I am going to have a poc, spliting most of the logic which is processes into microservices and functions. I will let you know how it goes.